# How to implement a FIFO listcontrol in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc, listcontrol

I need to implement a list control using MFC with the number of lines being fixed. It should Use FIFO with the number of lines being a fixed number. Is there an inbuilt option to this? Or a programmable method.

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting from scratch, then you could simply bind the controller's logic to something standard from STL, e.g std::list.

Comment: I'm using VS2008. But performance is very low when the number of lines increase. Is there a way to override the logic?